# How to pass variable within printf

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix

I am trying to echo a variable within a printf. I first prompt the user for input using the command below

```
printf 'Specify lrus [default 128]:         ' ;read -r lrus
```

Next it prompts the user again to see if he wants the input used from the previous question:

```
printf 'Are you sure you want $lrus lrus:       ' ;read -r ans
```

For example the output will look like the below:

```
Specify lrus [default 128]:     60
Are you sure you want 60 lrus:  yes
```

The above output is what I am trying to achieve allowing to pass the previous input variable to the next question using printf.

Comment: Use double quotes: `printf "..."`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using single-quotes.  Parameters are not expanded within single quotes.

Parameters are expanded in double-quotes, though:

```sh
printf "Are you sure you want $lrus lrus: "
```

If you're using a shell that supports `read -p`, then avoid the separate print.  Supplying a prompt this way is better (it understands your terminal width, for one thing):

```sh
read -p "Specify lrus [default 128]: " -r lrus
read -p "Are you sure you want $lrus lrus? " -r ans
```

Answer (score 9):

When using `printf`, use format specifiers. Put a `%s` where you want your value to go, and then put the value in the next parameter:

```
printf 'Are you sure you want %s lrus:       '  "$lrus"
read -r ans
```

This is safer and more robust than using double quotes to inject the variable into the `printf` format string. If you use double quotes, you will be unable to write out variables containing e.g. `100%`:

```
$ var='100%'; printf "Value is $var"
bash: printf: `%': missing format character

$ var='100%'; printf "Value is %s" "$var"
Value is 100%
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the SC2059](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2059) :

> Don't use variables in the printf format string. Use printf "..%s.."
> "$foo".

You can use:

```
printf "Are you sure you want %s lrus: " "$lrus"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
printf 'Are you sure you want '${lrus}' lrus:       ' ;read -r ans
```

or

```
printf "Are you sure you want ${lrus} lrus:       " ;read -r ans
```